# Arithmetic on Casted Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, pointer-arithmetic

The below code prints a passed string as hex values, I'm using it to check strings which include non-printable characters prior to transmission on a serial network. I understand the code but am just unsure why if we assume that an `int` on my system is 4 bytes, the pointer doesn't advance by four bytes each time `(unsigned int) *s++` is computed by the loop. Could someone please explain why this is the case? Is there some sort of operator precidence like general arithmetic?

```
static void printhexstring(const char *s) {
while(*s) {
    printf("<%02X> ", (unsigned int) *s++);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing a `char` pointer, dereferencing it, and then casting the result. You're not moving an `unsigned int` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("<%02X> ", (unsigned int) *s++);
```

You are incrementing the pointer `s` which is of type `char` and when this increment is done the pointer `s` is moved by one byte and not 4 bytes.
Casting has no effect on pointer arithmetic here.

`%X` converts an unsigned int to unsigned hexa and display the value out so you have the cast `unsigned int`

Comment: Thanks Gopi. The code does actually works as required, I was just curious as to why. Your answers clears it up!

Comment: @igloodan If it is confusing for you .. DO `while(*s) {
    printf("<%02X> ", (unsigned int) *s);
   s++;
}`